# How return the result of a search in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, search

I'm using asp.net mvc4, simplemembership and EF.

actually i have this code to search a user in my db.

HomeController :

```
        private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

        public ActionResult Index(string searchUser)
        {
            var user = from m in db.UserProfiles
                       select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchUser))
            {
                user = user.Where(s => s.UserName.Contains(searchUser));
            }

            return View(user);
        }
```

Index view :

```
 <div id="searchUser">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
            {   
                <p>
                    @Html.TextBox("searchUser")
                    <input type="submit" value="Chercher" />
                </p>     
            }
  </div>
             /********** PART 1 ***********/
        @{
            var db = new UsersContext();
            var list = db.UserProfiles.ToList();

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserName)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            }
        }
```

The part 1 here is obsolete. Instead of it, I would like to return the name of the user that I search for if he exist, otherwise I want to show a message to say he does not exist.

Actually, my request seem to work, but it returns nothing in the view, Is someone has an idea how can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: nothink if the user does not exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this,

on your controller, you always should return the same type for your view.

```
private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

public ActionResult Index(string searchUser = "")
{
    IEnumerable<User> result;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchUser))
    {
        var userFound = (from m in db.UserProfiles
                   where m.UserName.Constains(searchUser)
                   select m).FirstOrDefault(); // to take the first user you have found, but it is still an List.

            result = new List<User>() { userFound };
    }
    else 
    {
        result = (from m in db.UserProfiles
                 select m).ToList();
    }

    return View(result); // return the type for your view
}
```

And type your view with the same type on the Action and read it to display a table...

```
// type your view with IEnumerable<User>
@model IEnumerable<User>

<div id="searchUserForm">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {   
    <p>
        @Html.TextBox("searchUser")
        <input type="submit" value="Chercher" />
    </p>     
    }
</div>

@if (Model.Any()) // Model is an IEnumerable<User>
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>UserName</th>
        </tr>   
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserName)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
}
else 
{
    <p> No users to display.</p>
}
```

Comment: thanks, it returns the user I search for, but there is a way to not display all my users in my foreach loop, and just display the result of my search, when i search for one user ? Or is it just possible with using ajax ? (and thank you for correct my english :) )

Comment: I've tried @Html.DisplayForModel(Model.Select(m => m.UserName))  and it return a number, I keep looking

Comment: Chris, take a look at my edited code. In this case if you want to show the first record found, use `FirstOrDefault()` method, and you will get only one record. After this, add on a concret list, because your View is waiting for a List, and not a single user.

Comment: In the else condition of my controller I have the result with : `result = new List<User>().DefaultIfEmpty()` , with that, something is display only if I search for a user. Now, if my user doesn't exist, my else condition in the view doesn't display. why..?  I don't really understand what my `if(Model.Any())` condition mean...

Comment: Your Model is typed with IEnumrable<User> right, so every output of your action method should return this type to render this view, it is a MVC rule and you cannot change it (you also can return null but it is not a good thing to do). The method `.Any()` is an exceltion method of IEnumrable that return true if there is a record on the collection.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanations. So there is no way to get around this issue ? Or return something that is not a list, as a simple sentence, if my index action method return nothing ?

Comment: Yes, you can change the `@model` type on your View. If your model is null, you can check it `if (Model != null) { show data }`. Now, if you want to return diferent types, I would not recommend, but you could type your view with `object` type, and check the `GetType()` property, for sample: `if (Model != null && Model.GetType() == typeof(User)) { var user = (User)Model; /* show user data here */ }`.